# GET and POST in ajax

Tags: ajax, post, get

I have a C# web application which uses ajax method to GET and POST data. Is there any difference between GET and POST methods in passing data (in case of contentType,data,dataType)?

```
      $.ajax({
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: "url",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          data: { value: "data" },
                          dataType:"json",
success: function (data) {
                      alert(data);
                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert("In error");
                  }

              });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal form method also `GET` is used to sent some **insensitive small chunk of data** to server in querystring, whereas `POST` is used for sending **large and secure data** to the server
In case of using ajax **GET** is commonly used, **POST** is feasible only when you have to do DB interactions on server or there's some sensitive data involved, read more here  http://www.jquery4u.com/ajax/key-differences-post/

Answer (score 0):

GET encodes the information into the url, the more info you GET the longer your URL becomes.
POST stores data in an array and passes that array to the next page. your Url remains unmodified.

While that may not seem like a huge deal, URLs do have a maximum length and errors will ensue if you exceed it. In addition and call to a specific url may fail due to the modifications GET makes. Apart from that, They are similar enough in function to be interchangeable for most purposes.